# What's the best way to save a computer's identification to a database

Tags: database, ipv6, mac-address

Should I use IPv6, Mac Adress, or is there anything else that uniquely identifies each computer in the world?

My goal: I'm developing a software in which I want to give a free trial for users. So, what i thought, in order to prevent them from creating new accounts and keep using the free trials, is to save that computer's identification in a database to keep track of which computers already used a free trial account, so that computer can no longer use it even if the user creates a new account in the server. So is there any identification I could use to keep track of that? Or is there any better way to do something like this?

(I know one way or another users will be able to bypass that database changing their Mac Address for example, but most people won't, so i'm ok if just a small amount of people manage to cheat their way into getting the free trials...)

Comment: What is your goal?  All of those things can be spoofed or lied about in some way (VPN, MAC spoofing, user agent, etc).

Comment: I edited the question to explain better...

Comment: There are oh, so many ways. Of course, a unique identity is a definition that is less definitive than you might think. This question covers a whole industry nearly. Probably not something we can help you answer in a few paragraphs on StackOverflow unfortunately.